# Keyboard screen is not coming while typing in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am integrating facebook api in my application. It was working fine. I just import code in my other class. When I am trying to logged in I am not able to press keys on textbox and also keyboard screen is not coming.

But when I am clicking to alternative login link. I am able to typed there but after clicking on "Login" button I am seeing an error "Safari can't open ... ".

What about the above 2 reason ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check whether delegate methods of UITextfiled are running or not by substituting breakpoint at delegate methods of UITextfiled.